# Setting the value of a new global variable in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have this line in a function:

```
(let (v1) (v2)
    ... more code here ...
    (setq matchAgainstDirectory (
      read-directory-name "Set directory to match against:")))))))
```

`matchAgainstDirectory` is not in the list of values declared by `let`, so I assume that it will set a global value.

I want to set it to `nil` at some point, but if I press `M-x RET set-variable RET`, `matchAgainstDirectory` doesn't appear as a valid variable name. Why is this?

I know I can do `M-x ielm`, and write there `(setq matchAgainstDirectory ())`, but I'm looking for a shorter way of doing this. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: You can also use `M-: (setq matchAgainstDirectory nil) RET` which is slightly shorter than invoking ielm.

Comment: Phils, why don't you post an answer?

Comment: I didn't think it was quite what you were after, but sure.

Comment: In this case, it's much shorter/faster than the `ielm` version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(setq matchAgainstDirectory nil)` <kbd>RET</kbd> which is slightly shorter than invoking `ielm`.

Answer (score 4):

For the variable to show up when you do <kbd>M-x set-variable</kbd>, it must be defined via [`defvar`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html) because (as [the docs say)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Examining.html):

> M-x set-variable is limited to user option variables, but you can set
>   any variable with a Lisp expression, using the function setq.

So, define it as a variable with:

```
(defvar matchAgainstDirectory nil "some comment")
```

or

```
(defvar matchAgainstDirectory) ; value and comment are optional
```

So, put that in your code somewhere at the top-level (not in your `let` statement).

`setq` doesn't create a user option variable, it just creates an emacs lisp variable - which aren't intended to be set manually by the user via <kbd>M-x set-variable</kbd>.

Comment: So, if I define something via `setq` there's no function that will allow me to change it's variable? By the way, how did you create that button look for `M-x set-variable`?

Comment: @Geo Updated answer to give more information, but in short, 'no.' And for the button look, wrap in the tags <kbd>M-x set-variable</kbd> (which aren't interpreted in the comments).